# Difference between react and ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, react-native

I have read some docs and i do not really understand what are the differences between react and ionic frameworks.

Is one of them made from the other ?

I have to store local data. I suppose one of them is just web and javascript so data is only stored on server ? Or is it possible to do local storage with both of them.

Is it possible to host the app on a web server without having a "real" app ?

Thanks

Comment: I dont think you have "read some docs" or if you have , stop using bing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think that you are a little bit confused. I hope this clarify your doubts:

1. Ionic framework is a set of tools for create Hybrid apps using html/css and javascript, It is build using apache cordova and Angular 1. In the other hand you have React a library for build rich UX(User experience) web apps.
2. Ionic is not build on react. They are different purpose tools but you can use that together (Using IONIC 2).
3. In both cases you can use local storage, but if you want to store data in servers you have to build your own backend to provide data to the app They are front end oriented frameworks(no server side)
4. You can put Ionic code on a server it is simple JavaScript and HTML but this is not the purpose of the framework and if you do it, you loose the native apis of the device. In the case of React it is just a library and you can use it in an existing project using HTML and Javascript or build your app entirely with it.

You have a long road ahead, hope this help you.

Answer (score 2):

Ionic is an HTML5 mobile app development framework targeted at building hybrid mobile apps. They are essentially small websites running in a browser shell in an app that have access to the native platform layer.

React Native is the next generation of React – a JavaScript code library developed by Facebook and Instagram, which was released on Github in 2013. React Native lets you build mobile apps using only JavaScript.

They have their own way of functioning, below are few points on their differences:

Ionic is a regular web app, written using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, but it runs in a webview embedded in a native app instead of in a stand-alone mobile browser

**React Native has a completely different architecture:** instead of writing your UI using web technologies, it uses the React component model to render to native views.

Ionic is a Cordova based app that wrap current web app into a mobile application. It uses the android existing web view to render the app so the file size is quite small
Meanwhile react native create bridge between JavaScript and native component.

When it comes to memory usage, Ionic framework uses more than react native apps
The Ionic app is slower at loading videos because it needs to download from other server, while in react native, it caches the tiles so it loads faster.

When it comes to integration, react native can use every client based JavaScript modules from npm (node package manager) whereas Ionic uses only the Cordova-based code.

Ionic is a framework that creates an idea of writing code only once
React native is not a write once and run anywhere framework, but is popularly touted as a **“learn once, write anywhere”** framework
Ionic Framework app needs to use device features and APIs through Apache Cordova plugins.

With react native you can access any device component or API
Based  on the points above, you can see the difference in their functionalities, so if you want to go for something  that creates  performant iOS and Android apps that feel at home on their respective platforms ten you can opt for React Native.

And, if you are targeted at building hybrid mobile apps, Ionic is the best choice!